# How can I retrieve the new timeline data from the API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

At the [f8-conference](http://f8.facebook.com/)  Facebook just announced the new timeline view. This is based on the new [Open-Graph model](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

**The question is, how is this data retrieved via the API?**

Retrieval should address a number of complexities:

- The filtered nature should be just like in the online view, i.e. not everything from the ticker should show up
- Even more, the granularity of the timeline view should be reflected just like on the webpage (more detail today, less detail in the past, but the option to dig deeper at any time)
- The [aggregation view](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/define-units/) of app data should be supported
- The cover image should be part of the data

Right now, it is not obvious to me if this is or will be possible at all.

Comment: Wait a few days and I'm sure more documentation an api's will be rolled out. It's been out less than a day.

Comment: Also curious about this. I'm clear on how to add data to the open graph, but completely unclear if I have access to this data (expecially data created by other 3rd party apps.)

Comment: Ok, I've done some experiments with curl.  Actions publishing/reading via graph api (post/get) basically work.  But the documents do not mention how to the access the aggression via graph api. I hope it won't be another FB non-open function like [facebook questions](http://www.quora.com/Will-there-be-a-Facebook-Questions-API-and-if-so-what-will-it-do).

Comment: your own application data can be accessed with: https://graph.facebook.com/me/YOUR_NAMESPACE:YOUR_ACTION/YOUR_OBJECT?access_token=A_TOKEN

Answer (score 2):

In answer to [agam360’s](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7527059/how-can-i-retrieve-the-new-timeline-data-from-the-api#comment10121439_7570899) further question in the comments,

> But how can we get that "Cover Photos" Id? (looping though all of the Graph data?!)

Use FQL, and take `name="Cover Photos"` into the WHERE condition of your query too. (But keep in mind that this album name is locale dependend, so if you should be querying the data in another locale than english, you’ll have to adapt the search term.)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer to the fourth bullet:

There is a new photo album called "Cover Photos" with the cover image on position 1. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to find the positioning coordinates that define the viewport on the image.

{edit} There's now a `cover` field on a user which returns the cover photo and the x/y offset needed to display it the same way it's displayed on Facebook {/edit}

Comment: But how can we get that "Cover Photos" Id? (looping though all of the Graph data?!)